# Java MAT histogram class with "Unknown" tag

Tags: android, eclipse-memory-analyzer

What does the Unknown -tag mean when you open (Android) heap dump with MAT, go to histogram, the then select e.g. "merge shortest paths..." for your class of interest?

Like here:

```
 class android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager @ 0x40b083f8 Unknown
```

There can be also other tags like Thread or System class with the Unknown.

I ask this as someone claimed that the Unknowns are subject to GC and could thus be ignored in memory leak analysis. I failed to find a reliable source for this. Can someone verify this?

Answer (score 1):

From [MAT documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Fconcepts%2Fgcroots.html);

**Unknown**
**An object of unknown root type. Some dumps, such as IBM Portable Heap Dump files, do not have root information. For these dumps the MAT parser marks objects which are have no inbound references or are unreachable from any other root as roots of this type. This ensures that MAT retains all the objects in the dump.**

So my assumption is Dalvik doesn't have root information for some objects or MAT doesn't recognize Dalvik heaps fully. "Unknown" type shouldn't relate to GC'ability.